# Pillow неправильно работает paste изображения, не пойму, почему так

Tags: python, pil, pillow

[image: Фон цитаты]

[image: Аватарка]

[image: Кавычки]

```
    # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageOps
rsize = (700, 400)
img = Image.open('suka.png')#аватарка
res = Image.open('fon.png')#фон
res.paste(img, (25, 100), img)
res.show
q = Image.new('RGBA',(40,40),color=(0,0,0,0))
q = Image.open("q.png").resize((40, 40), Image.LANCZOS).convert('RGBA')#кавычки
qf = q.copy().transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT).transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM).convert('RGBA')
q.show()
qf.show()
res.paste(q, (240, 240))
res.paste(qf, (300, 300))
res.show()
```

1. Фон
2. Аватарка
3. Кавычки(белые на прозрачном фоне)

В чём собственно проблема?  На скрине ниже результат, у кавычек прозрачный фон меняется на чёрный, не могу исправить, в чём проблема?(Справа на результате по отдельности открытые кавычки)

[image: Результат]

Comment: Обратите внимание, что случае с аватаркой вы передаёте в `paste` три аргумента, а в случае с кавычками — почему-то всего два

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    Заменил `paste` на `aplha_composite`  и магическим образом всё заработало, как надо, чуть доработал, но суть видна